# Trigger to update row in another table

Tags: mysql

This is a select statement that calculates the average rating of a song in my database

```
SELECT *, (tab.rating_sum/tab.rating_count) as rating_average FROM
(SELECT song_id, COUNT(rating) rating_count, SUM(rating) rating_sum FROM ratings
GROUP BY song_id) tab

INNER JOIN SONGS WHERE SONGS.id = tab.song_id
```

I need to insert the column rating_average from the table RATINGS into the table SONGS when a new rating is inserted in RATINGS. I also need to make sure it goes into the proper song_id column. How can I do this with a trigger? I have been ripping my hair out.

This is the best that I can come up with, but I have no idea what I am doing with triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rating_trig ON ratings FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
UPDATE SONGS SET
rating = SELECT (tab.rating_sum/tab.rating_count) as rating_average FROM
(SELECT song_id, COUNT(rating) rating_count, SUM(rating) rating_sum FROM ratings
GROUP BY song_id) tab

INNER JOIN SONGS WHERE SONGS.id = tab.song_id
END
```

TABLE LAYOUTS:

RATINGS | song_id, rating, username
SONGS | id, rating, song_name

Comment: I have tried a bunch of things to no avail, I don't remember everything I have tried because I haven't made any progress. I was hoping someone could give me a basic layout for what I might need to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming a table structure like this one:

```
use test;

create table song(
  song_id integer,
  rating_avg double,
  rating_sum integer,
  rating_count integer);

create table rating(
  song_id integer,
  user_id integer,
  rating integer);
```

Define the following triggers:

```
delimiter $$

create trigger bi_song before insert on test.song
for each row
begin
  set NEW.rating_sum = 0;
  set NEW.rating_count = 0;
  set NEW.rating_avg = NULL;
end
$$

create trigger ai_rating after insert on test.rating
for each row
begin
  update song set
    rating_sum = rating_sum + NEW.rating,
    rating_count = rating_count + 1,
    rating_avg = rating_sum / rating_count
    where song_id = NEW.song_id;
end
$$
delimiter ;
```

And it should work like this:

```
mysql> insert into song(song_id) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from song;
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
| song_id | rating_avg | rating_sum | rating_count |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
|       1 |       NULL |          0 |            0 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into rating(song_id, user_id, rating) values (1, 1000, 5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from song;
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
| song_id | rating_avg | rating_sum | rating_count |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
|       1 |          5 |          5 |            1 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into rating(song_id, user_id, rating) values (1, 1001, 7);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> select * from song;
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
| song_id | rating_avg | rating_sum | rating_count |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
|       1 |          6 |         12 |            2 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is very simplified, just to illustrate how to work with triggers.
In a real application, you would have more columns, indexes, etc.

Comment: this is great. what exactly does the first trigger do? can i leave that one out if those default values are 0? i already have a trigger on that table and it won't let me create another one

Comment: here is the message for context: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: so actually if the default values are 0 then can I change it to AFTER INSERT on SONGS to get rid of the error?

Comment: The first trigger sets the fields to 0 / NULL values. An AFTER INSERT on song will not work, since the data needs to be fixed before writing to the table, not after.
Having defaults values for columns will work as well, a trigger is not really required for this. A trigger prevents people to insert songs with a rating value (without ratings).
About error #1235, if you have multiple triggers on the same event and same table with different pieces of logic in them, you need to define only one trigger and put all the logic in one place. Feel free to accept the answer ;) Regards

Comment: Perfect, figured it out. THANK YOU!