# Update table when another table is updated

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables TESTUserInfo and BlockRanking.

TestUserInfo is a bunch of users info and totals for their specific user. Each user also has a zone associated with their user.

In BlockRanking I combine all of the users with each zone and sum all of the total points for that zone.

I have this query to insert values into table BlockRanking from TESTUserInfo and it works.

```
INSERT INTO BlockRanking (zone, total) 
SELECT zone, SUM(total) 
FROM TESTUserInfo 
GROUP BY zone 
ORDER BY SUM(total) DESC
```

Now I am trying to do something similar to this but I want to update BlockRanking when TESTUserInfo is update. I specifically want to update the zones and the total of those zones in BlockRanking after they are grouped by.

I would like this to be a trigger so when TESTUserInfo is updated BlockRanking will also be updated, or on a time basis. If These are not possible just a query will work too.

Comment: Have a look at MySQL triggers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the suggestion. I have already looked at that site and could not figure out the update for my query. The insert works great but I cannot update the BlockRanking table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) to run tasks when certain queries are run on a table. A trigger runs once for each inserted row. Instead of aggregating, we can keep track of the totals that are added into the TESTUserInfo table as they arrive.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_totals AFTER INSERT ON TESTUserInfo
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BlockRanking
       (zone, total)
       VALUES 
       (NEW.zone, NEW.total)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        total = total + VALUES(total);
  END;
```

Note that `zone` would have to be a unique index in `BlockRanking`.

If it is possible for rows to be updated or removed in TESTUserInfo, you would similarly have to create triggers. For an `UPDATE` trigger, you could do something like: `total = total + NEW.total - OLD.total`.

**See also:**

[Trigger to update row in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122712/trigger-to-update-row-in-another-table)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed. I am using phpmyadmin and am fairly new to it. It says there is an error for "total = total + VALUES('total');" I am also beginning my trigger at insert because I believe that the code previous is not necessary in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I am not currently able to debug. You could try `total = total + VALUES(total)`, and maybe explicitly name the table throughout the query, so `BlockRanking.zone` instead of `zone` and `BlockRanking.total` instead of `total`. Giving me the actual error message would also be helpful. :)

Note that I initially made a mistake, the values inserted should be `(NEW.zone, NEW.total)`, not `(NEW.zone, total + NEW.total)`. At this point, no previous `total` is available yet. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` takes care of summing.

Comment: The specific error that I am getting is #1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "total")' at line 6.

Comment: The code I am using is                                                                               INSERT INTO BlockRanking
       (BlockRanking.zone, BlockRanking.total)
       VALUES 
       (NEW.zone, NEW.total)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        BlockRanking.total = BlockRanking.total +  VALUES('total')

Comment: Try `VALUES(BlockRanking.total)` (i.e., without apostrophes).

Comment: That was the fix that I needed! Thank you so much. You were very helpful.